# Let $m,n \in\mathbb Z$. If $m \le n \le m$ then $m = n$.

Tags: relations, order-theory

I an learning proofs with $\mathbb{N}$. 
Here are my axioms:

a)If $m,n \in\mathbb N$ then $m + n \in\mathbb N$

b)If $m,n \in\mathbb N$ then $mn \in\mathbb N$

c) $0 \notin\ \mathbb N$

d) For every $m \in\mathbb Z$, we have $m \in\mathbb N$ or $m = 0$ or $-m \in\mathbb N$

**Definition:** $m > n  \Leftrightarrow m - n \in\mathbb N$.

By the way, I would greatly appreciate if someone could please explain to me why this is. My strategy is to use a contradiction.

**Proposition 1:** (that I have proven)

For $m \in\mathbb Z$, one and only one of the following is true: $m \in\mathbb N$, $-m \in\mathbb N$, $m = 0$.

I have proven $1 \in\mathbb N$ and: Let $m,n,p \in\mathbb Z$. If $m < n$ and $n < p$ then $m < p$ by deriving $p - m = (p - n) + (n - m) \in\mathbb N$.

I have also proven: For each $n \in\mathbb N$ there exists $m \in\mathbb N$ such that $m > n$

**Proposition 2:**

Let $m,n \in\mathbb Z$. If $m \le n \le m$ then $m = n$.

I get confused because of the equality within the $\leq$. How could I approach this? By separating $<$ and $=$ ?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $m-n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Now proceed with a result you have proven.

Comment: As for $m\leq n \leq m$, that means that $m\leq n$ *and* $n\leq m$.  Since $m=m$, you have that $n$ is sandwiched inbetween, and therefore must also equal $m$.  (If you don't believe that statement, then consider what happens if $n>m$ or if $n<m$ and arrive at a contradiction)

Comment: To prove anything about $\;m \le n\;$, you would need to know its definition in terms of $\;>\;$, but you haven't provided us with one.  Is it $\;\lnot(m > n)\;$?  Or $\;n > m \;\lor\; n = m\;$?

Comment: @MarnixKlooster Hi! Thank you for your feedback. I have edited my original post to include the definition.

Comment: @Johnathan You added the definition of $\;>\;$, which you'd already given earlier in the post (directly after the axiom list).  Instead, what is needed is the definition for $\;\le\;$.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster Oups! It is not defined like $m > n$ or any of your suggestions. :/ sorry. I am only given what is above.

Comment: @Johnathan Then you cannot prove this, until you're given (or you've chosen) a definition.  Note that [@AaronMaroja](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/143413/aaron-maroja)'s answer assumes the definition is $\;m \le n \;\equiv\; \lnot(m>n)\;$, when he says that "$m > n$ \[...\] is a contradiction", viz. with his assumption $m \le n$.

Comment: That's right, I've chosen that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First proposition**

- If $m \in \mathbb N$ and $-m \in \mathbb N$ then $ 0 \in \mathbb N$, absurd.
- If $m \in \mathbb N$ and $ m = 0$, absurd.
- Similar to $-m$.

Therefore it folows the affirmation.

**Second proposition**

If $m \leq n \leq m$ then $m - n \in \mathbb Z$ and by the first proposition only one of those $3$ holds, then if $m - n \in \mathbb N$ then $m>n$ by definition, which is a contradiction. Similar if $n-m \in \mathbb N$.

Thus the only possibility is $m - n = 0$.

Comment: @Johnathan Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Sorry for the late reply. Ok, so if $m,n \in\mathbb Z$, then I understand that $m+(−n) \in\mathbb Z$ and that the result is exclusively 0, a natural number or its inverse is a natural number. I am confused on how you derive your contradiction from: $m -n \in\mathbb N$ then $m>n$ by definition. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Comment: As $m\leq n$ by hypothesis then if $m> n$ you have a contradiction.

Comment: I think I understand! Is it a contradiction relative to the proposition? For example, $m > n$ contradicts $m \le n$, and similarly, $n > m$ contradicts  $n \le m$, right? Hence, m = n is the only option that keeps the proposition true, right? Wow! It's so simple! Thank you! :)

Comment: $m - n = 0$ is the only ´possibility, that's right!

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, here is a more 'logical' version of [Aaron Maroja](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/143413/aaron-maroja)'s argument, spelling out all steps in full formal detail, and referring only to the axioms, not to e.g. your proposition 1.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\mbox{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$As discussed in the comments for this question, the answer to your question

> I get confused because of the equality within the $\leq$. How could I
>   approach this? By separating $<$ and $=$ ?

is: by applying the definition of $\;\le\;$.  And since you've not been provided with such a definition, we will use
$$
m \le n \;\equiv\; \lnot(m>n)
$$

---

We can now start at the most complex side of the theorem, and calculate as follows:

$$\calc
m \le n \le m
\calcop\equiv{definition of $\;\le\;$, twice; definition of $\;<\;$, twice}
\lnot(m - n \in \mathbb N) \;\land\; \lnot (n - m \in \mathbb N)
\calcop\then{axiom $\ref d$, twice -- the only way forward using only the axioms}
(m - n = 0 \;\lor\; -(m - n) \in \mathbb N) \;\land\; (n - m = 0 \;\lor\; -(n - m) \in \mathbb N)
\calcop\equiv{arithmetic: simplify; logic: extract common disjunct}
m = n \;\lor\; (n - m \in \mathbb N \;\land\; m - n \in \mathbb N)
\calcop{\tag{*} \then}{axiom $\ref a$ -- this is the key step in this proof}
m = n \;\lor\; (n - m) + (m-n) \in \mathbb N
\calcop\equiv{arithmetic: simplify}
m = n \;\lor\; 0 \in \mathbb N
\calcop\equiv{axiom $\ref c$; logic: simplify}
m = n
\endcalc$$

---

Note that except for the key step $\ref *$, all the steps in the above calculation are almost forced by the desire to simplify, and keeping our goal in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $m \ne n$. That means: $m < n < m$. Then by definition, $m−n∈N$ and $n-m∈N$. By axiom (a): $0=m-n+n-m∈N$. Came to contradiction by axiom (c), so $m$ is indeed equal to $n$.

Comment: If $m \ne n$, then I can understand that (WLOG) $n < m$, or vice versa. I don't understand, however, how you could have $m < n < m$? That would imply that $m \ne m$.

Comment: Notice that $\neg (a \wedge b)$ is equivalent to $\neg a \vee \neg b$. So you can't say that $m< n$ **and** $n< m$, that is $m < n < m$. The correct would be $m>n$ or $m < n$.